# Adding data dynamically in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

My `UITableView` contains messages (a message has a text and an image). At the beginning, my `UITableView` is empty:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *messages;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView* tableView;

- (void)viewDidLoad{  
    self.messages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
```

The `UITableViewDelegate`, and `UITableViewDataSource` is connected in the IB. When I get a message, I want to show it on the `UITableView` as follow:

```
- (void)didReceiveMessage:(NSNotification *) notification{

    //- extract message
    NSDictionary* userInfo = notification.userInfo;
    Message* msg = [userInfo objectForKey:kNotificationMessage];

    //- update table
    [self.messages addObject:msg];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [self scrollTableViewToBottom];
}
```

At this point, my Messages mutable array contains exactly the message. However, when reloading the `UITableView`, the message seems to point to another address.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{   

    Message *message = [self.messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];     
    cell.textLabel.text = message.text;
    cell.imageView.image = [message getImage];
}
```

the message is not nil, but message.text is nil. I doubt that the userInfo is release when getting out of function `didReceiveMessage`. So, that's why the message is not nil, but point to an address that contains nothing. What I tried to do is retain or copy the message before adding it to the `NSMutableArray` messages like:

```
- (void)didReceiveMessage:(NSNotification *) notification{

    //- extract message
    NSDictionary* userInfo = notification.userInfo;
    Message* msg = [userInfo objectForKey:kNotificationMessage];
    Message* copyMsg = [msg copy];

    //- update table
    [self.messages addObject:copyMsg];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [self scrollTableViewToBottom];
}
```

But I am afraid that doing such thing will make the program to be leak. Do you have any solution? Or explain me why?

More info:

my Message class looks like this:

```
@interface Message : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSString *text;

@end
```

Do I need to change it to @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* text; ????

Comment: wheres the rest of your code?

Comment: add your text and image in different arry then show them in table by using tableView delegate method

Comment: I got some problem related to text format while posting question. While the question was not completed, you could answer it. I really admire you. :-)

Comment: Do you use ARC? And, how do you declare text variable (strong,nonatomic) in Message object?

Comment: I think I use ARC. This is the default setting of XCODE5, iOS7, and I do not change anything

Comment: nmh: I declare like this : @property (nonatomic, assign) NSString *text;

Comment: in didReceiveMessage.. After assigning your Message Obj with  [userInfo objectForKey:kNotificationMessage], Did you check if msg.text has any value?

Comment: Yes, the msg.text is the text that I expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Message` object, you declare text variable:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSString *text
```

This is the root cause why `text`is nil when you get it's value. If you set value

`NSString *s = @"SomeValue"; 
 Message.text=s;`

`s variable` is released after that and your text will be released too. So, you should declare `text` variable is `strong` to keep its value.